# correlation values generated through excel and i want to make matrix even look

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I generated a correlation matrix by excel and it have following type of output:

```
                 tae-miR1127    tae-miR1131   tae-miR164    tae-miR5084     tae-miR1138
tae-miR1127            1                
tae-miR1131       0.335050711        1          
tae-miR164        0.167933504   -0.134901833       1        
tae-miR5084      -0.140902598   0.119780666   -0.189285165       1  
tae-miR1138      -0.031264072   0.16572515    -0.178381246    0.080697284       1
```

And i want to make this output like -

```
                 tae-miR1127    tae-miR1131     tae-miR164     tae-miR5084      tae-miR1138
tae-miR1127            1        0.335050711     0.167933504    -0.140902598     -0.031264072
tae-miR1131      0.335050711          1         -0.134901833    0.119780666      0.16572515
tae-miR164       0.167933504    -0.134901833         1          -0.189285165    -0.178381246
tae-miR5084     -0.140902598    0.119780666     -0.189285165        1            0.080697284
tae-miR1138     -0.031264072    0.16572515      -0.178381246    0.080697284          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. You could try this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %h;
my @a;
while (<DATA>) {
    if ($. == 1) {
        @a=split;
        printLine([' ', @a]);
        next;
    }
    my @b=split;
    for (1..$#b) {
        $h{$b[0]}{$a[($_-1)]}=$b[$_];
        $h{$a[($_-1)]}{$b[0]}=$b[$_];
    }
}
for (@a) {
    printLine([$_, @{$h{$_}}{@a}]);
}

sub printLine {
    my ($a) = @_;

    for (@$a) {
        printf "%-16s",$_;
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
                 tae-miR1127    tae-miR1131   tae-miR164    tae-miR5084     tae-miR1138
tae-miR1127            1                
tae-miR1131       0.335050711        1          
tae-miR164        0.167933504   -0.134901833       1        
tae-miR5084      -0.140902598   0.119780666   -0.189285165       1  
tae-miR1138      -0.031264072   0.16572515    -0.178381246    0.080697284       1
```

Output:

```
                tae-miR1127     tae-miR1131     tae-miR164      tae-miR5084     tae-miR1138     
tae-miR1127     1               0.335050711     0.167933504     -0.140902598    -0.031264072    
tae-miR1131     0.335050711     1               -0.134901833    0.119780666     0.16572515      
tae-miR164      0.167933504     -0.134901833    1               -0.189285165    -0.178381246    
tae-miR5084     -0.140902598    0.119780666     -0.189285165    1               0.080697284     
tae-miR1138     -0.031264072    0.16572515      -0.178381246    0.080697284     1
```